# Why does this happen when I enter ' into the console?

Tags: bash, debian

I have been noticing some strange behaviour when I type characters like `'` or the backtick. Whenever I type it, the `>` symbol shows up everytime I type something, and everything I type seemingly does not do anything. But when I type the character again, it returns to normal.

```
user@debian:~$ '
> command
> '
-bash:
command
: command not found
user@debian:~$
```

What is this feature? As far as I know, the man page for bash did not say anything about this

---

Debian Jessie

Comment: This question is a duplicate, but to explain shortly. It's what you get when you are supposed to continue a command, for example if you type `"` you should type another `"` to close that. An example is if you want to echo mutliple lines, you would type `echo " (newline)
foo"`.

Comment: @DisplayName Yes, that answered it. I flagged my question as a duplicate